# Bash functions returning values meanwhile altering global variables

Tags: bash, global-variables, return-value

I'm just struggling with bash functions, and trying to **return string values meanwhile some global variable is modified inside the function**. An example:

```
MyGlobal="some value"

function ReturnAndAlter () {
  MyGlobal="changed global value"
  echo "Returned string"
}

str=$(ReturnAndAlter)
echo $str            # prints out 'Returned value' as expected
echo $MyGlobal       # prints out the initial value, not changed
```

This is because $(...) (and also `...` if used instead) cause the function to have its own environment, so the global variable is never affected.

I found a very dirty workaround by returning the value into another global variable and calling the function only using its name, but think that there should be a cleaner way to do it.

My dirty solution:

```
MyGlobal="some value"
ret_val=""

function ReturnAndAlter () {
  ret_val="Returned string"
  MyGlobal="changed value"
}

ReturnAndAlter            # call the bare function
str=$ret_val              # and assign using the auxiliary global ret_val 
echo $str
echo $MyGlobal            # Here both global variables are updated.
```

Any new ideas? Some way of calling functions that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Setting global variables is the only way a function has of communicating directly with the shell that calls it. The practice of "returning" a value by capturing the standard output is a bit of a hack necessitated by the shell's semantics, which are geared towards making it easy to call *other* programs, not making it easy to do things *in* the shell itself.

So, don't worry; no, you aren't missing any cool tricks. You're doing what the shell allows you to do.

Answer (score 0):

The `$(…)` (command expansion) is run in a sub-shell.
All changes inside the sub-shell are lost when the sub-shell close.

It is usually a bad idea to use both printing a result and changing a variable inside a function. Either make all variables or just use *one* printed string.

There is no other solution.

Comment: @SergioGarcíaGalán Fine, then you could use it.

Comment: Finally I got to restructure my whole script so that this kind of functions will not be needed now. Glad it was at early stages :-D Thanks everyone!